# ListView Onitemclicklistener not working getInt()

Tags: android, android-webview

My problem is Onitemclicklistener not working I hope you help!!!

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,Webhtml.class);
            intent.putExtra("page",position);
            startActivity(intent);

        }
    }

);
```

page 2 webhtml

```
public class Webhtml extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_webhtml);
        WebView webView = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

        Intent data = getIntent();
        int pag = data.getExtras().getInt("page");

        pag++;

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/html/" +pag +".html");

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a little more details about the error? What is the `listView` variable bound to? Is the problem in the `getInt("page")` line? If so, what is the error you see?

Comment: Click is not working on the listView  i can't open a webhtml (Activity2)

Comment: listView is  Id ListView